# Bash parameter shell expansion counting unknown character

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to compare the values of two strings; "$mongoOne" and "true"

```
mongoOne=$(docker exec -it mongo-1 mongo --quiet --eval "d=db.isMaster(); print( d['ismaster'] )" )
```

This is a simple docker command that returns true/false depending on whether or not a node is master.

If I echo $mongoOne, i see the response:

```
true
```

However, when I run:

```
if [ "$mongoOne" = "true" ]
then 
  echo "master"
else
  echo "secondary"
fi
```

The code responds with secondary instead of master.

I've found that when using parameter shell expansion to count the characters in $mongoOne, I see the following:

```
echo ${#mongoOne}
5
```

mongoOne contains 5 characters, not the expected 4.

I've tried piping this into a file, and I see no trailing whitespace or new lines.

Can anyone advise on what this 5th character could be?

Comment: Probably a newline.

Comment: You could place an `echo "[$mongoOne]"` just before `echo "secondary"` to see what its value is.

Comment: `declare -p mongoOne` should show you the true value of `mongoOne` better than simply echoing its value to the terminal. (Depending on your version of `bash`, the output will probably show a trailing carriage return in a less than clear fashion.)

Comment: For older versions of bash, `declare -p mongoOne | LC_ALL=C cat -vt` would be an even better way to see what the variable actually contains. If it prints `declare -- mongoOne="true^M"` that means there's a carriage return character at the end of the variable's value.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the responses all. After some more digging, I found a Git issue for this exact problem: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/8513

The fix was removing -it and replacing it with --tty=false.

```
mongoOne=$(docker exec --tty=false mongo-1 mongo --quiet --eval "d=db.isMaster(); print( d['ismaster'] )" )
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if [ $(grep -o "$mongoOne") = "true" ]
then 
  echo "master"
else
  echo "secondary"
fi
```

You might have better luck with this.  The -o command to grep, only matches the exact text that you want.

I'm also not completely clear on how "if" compares strings, to be honest.  If I needed to do something like this, I'd probably want the MongoOne variable to contain "1" rather than "true," because I know that numerical comparison works directly, via subtraction.  Text is for users; computers need numbers.

Comment: `if` doesn't do *any* comparisons. It simply checks the exit status of a command. `[` is the command that actually performs the comparison. And `-o` does *not* mean "match exact extent"; it means output the match, rather than the entire line containing the match.